# Custom type conversion with AutoMapper.Data

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

My application reads from either a Sql Server or Oracle database.

Most of the queries are very simple and most of the time there is no difference in query semantics. I decided not to use datasets but to convert results into DTOs directly:

```
SomeDto data = GetResult<SomeDto>("SELECT * FROM table");
```

In the `GetResult` method, I use the `AutoMapper` with `AutoMapper.Data` extensions. Following is the simplified content of the `GetResult` method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetResult(string query) 
{
    using(DbConnection db = GetConnection()) 
    {
        var command = db.CreateCommand()
        command.CommandText = query;

        return mapper.map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(dataReader);
    }
}
```

Thanks to the AutoMapper.Data extensions, I'm able to convert the data reader directly to DTO with the automapper configuration.

```
cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
```

**The problem**

The Oracle and Sql Server database have the same structure but there are some inconsistencies in the column types.

For example, Oracle's `NUMBER(8)` is interpreted as `int` and Sql Server's `NUMBER(8,0)` is interpreted as `decimal` eventhough it is really always an integer (yes, it should be int but I can't do anything about it). If the target type in DTO doesn't correspond, type mismatch exception is thrown.

```
public class SomeDto 
{
     //works fine with Oracle
     //throws exception when using Sql Server
     public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot change the database types and I expect more similar inconsistencies to show up so I figured that I configure the automapper.

Something like:

- if the property of the DTO is of type X and the value assigned to it is of specific type, use this explicit conversion.

E.g.

```
mapper.map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(dataReader, options => {
    options.ConfigureMap()
            //simple explicit cast, no loss of precision expected
           .UseThisCastWhenMappingToDTO<decimal, int>(decimalInput => (int)decimalInput);
});
```

**The question**

Is is possible to say something like `UseThisCastWhenMappingToDTO<TSource, TTarget>` with AutoMapper?

Because it looks like it could be possible but I have no idea how to do it. I could not find any documentation or examples on how you can specify a custom configuration when mapping the `IDataReader` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Try creating a map from decimal to int.